# Find abbreviations but not partially-capitalised words

Tags: python, regex, string

How to find all possible abbreviated words like CPR and S.O.S. Regex pattern = [A-Z][A-Z]+ can find all words with caps but I want to exclude words like REgex.

```
line2 = "What does CPR and S.O.S means ?"

match = re.search(r'[A-Z][A-Z]+', line2)  
if match:                      
    print 'found', match.group() 
else:
    print 'did not find'
```

EDIT: Taking the advice to separate the questions into two separate posts.

Comment: Separate questions are a good thing.  Jeff Atwood says multipart-questions aren't the right kind of questions for S.O.: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the regex `[A-Z\.]+\s`. However, it requires whitespace after the abbreviation.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> line2 = "What does CPR and S.O.S means ?"
>>> re.findall(r'\b[A-Z\.]+\b', line2)
['CPR', 'S.O.S']
```